# version appearing twice in url when using versioned api with Azure API Managment

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-api-management

I am integrated my versioned APIs with swagger and with Azure API Management. The version number comes twice once I import the swagger definition API Management. Is there a better way we could do this with swagger or with API managment so that second V1 does not appear?

API ManagmentURL https://my-apimgnt.azure-api.net/myapi-dev/v1/api/v1/user/Skills/get

Direct URL/backend
https://jsdevsf.api.mydomain.com/api/v1/user/Skills

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/user/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
```

Swagger Definition

```
{
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
"version": "2.0",
"title": "MyAPI 2.0",
"termsOfService": "None",
"contact": {
"name": "mySupport",
"email": "support@my.com"
}
},
"basePath": "/my.Application/my.WebAPI",
"paths": {

    "/api/v1/user/Skills/get/{ProductId}": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Paths are relative to the basePath or Base URI.

Looks like you just need to remove the `/api/v1` part from your swagger definition.  So your definition should be:

```
{
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
"version": "2.0",
"title": "MyAPI 2.0",
"termsOfService": "None",
"contact": {
"name": "mySupport",
"email": "support@my.com"
}
},
"basePath": "/my.Application/my.WebAPI",
"paths": {

    "/user/Skills/get/{ProductId}": {}
}
```

To do this from Azure, go to Design -> Front End -> OpenAPI Specification Editor

From here you should see basePath and paths.  Swagger Editor should also display and allow you to configure these values.

Comment: not sure how to do this. when swagger.json is generated it comes with /api/v1. How do I ensure that it does not show up under path.

Comment: Updated my answer.  If you can't find it, please state what editor you're using.